# Unity launcher Libre Office bug

Tags: 12.04, libreoffice, unity

Hi all whenever I open a Libre Office document in 12.04 it has invisible icons in the launcher (see screenshot)

[image: bug]

This is really distracting and bugs the crap out of my OCD. It happens even when using the default icon set.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Try `unity --reset-icons` and post your finds.

Comment: @tijybba thanks I ran it. If I have the default Libre Office launchers locked in the panel this doesn't happen. I seldomly use Libre Office though and unlock the default launchers. This bug happens as soon as there is no default launcher locked to the Unity-Launcher and you open a document with one of the Libre Office applications.

Comment: This is a bug and so is off-topic for Ask Ubuntu. You should instead [file a bug report](http://askubuntu.com/q/5121/12864)